# What happens if ret is used without a call?

Tags: assembly, avr

I am very new to assembly and I am wondering about the behavior of ret. If i never use a call during the code, but put a ret at the end, the code just goes back to the beginning. Is this a default behavior when there is no call used? If I used a jmp, would that affect the behavior of ret if there is still no call used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`call` puts the next instruction's address into the call stack, then jumps to the target address.

`ret` pops the last address from the call stack, then jumps here. It seems that if the stack is empty, it returns `0x00000000`, and it jumps to the start of the program.  *At least in some systems. You should not use this because of address space violations.*

`jmp` has *no effect* on the call stack, so it won't modify the behavior of `ret`.

Edit: As @PeterCordes wrote; if you use `push` or `pop`, they can write stack memory, and `ret` would pop that.

Comment: If you used other instructions like `push` before `ret`, it would pop whatever you pushed. 
 `call` isn't the only instruction that can write to stack memory.  `ret` is basically just a pop into the instruction pointer.

Comment: Quick aside, if you are interested in looking beyond your current processor: While AVR and x86 and many other processors return to a return address taken from the stack, there are also processors which return to a return address taken from a special register.

Answer (score 3):

In many systems, the bootup/startup code actually *calls* the `main()` function (or its equivalent), e.g. bare metal AVR programs using  https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/ (That has the advantage that the compiler can compile `main()` as a function like any other, not needing any special treatment).

So when your user code in `main()` does `ret` (even though your user code itself never actually calls anthing), your user code will return from that implicit call and the bootup/startup code will continue running.

Now the question is what the bootup/startup code does after `main()` has returned. It could go into an endless busy loop, halt the system, power down, reboot, etc.